# How to display item from server once a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

student here! So I created a function that runs an `$.ajax` request, and for each item, I output html to the DOM. Well, check it out:

```
  function getLinks (){
  let blogLinks;
  $.ajax(settings).then(function(data, status, xhr){
    data.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      let id = item._id;
      if (item.title){
        blogLinks = `<li><a class="link" href=#${item.title}>${item.title}</a></li>`
        $($findUl).append(blogLinks);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

this var might be useful info as well:

```
let $blogViewAll =
    $(`<div class="blog-view">
        <h3>Check Out These Blogs</h3>
        <div class="column-1">
          <ul class="link-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column-2"></div>
      </div>`);

let $findUl = $($blogViewAll).find('.link-list');
```

It's doing exactly what I want it to do and appending the links to the page. Now I want to click on the link and have the message body display on the page. So I'm trying this:

```
$findUl.on('click', function(e){
  $.ajax(settings).then(function(data, status, xhr){
    data.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
      //since you clicked on that link
      //I should look at what you clicked
      //match it to the corresponding obj{item.body}
      //and display it, but I don't know how to match and grab :(
    })
  })
});
```

And that's where I'm stuck! Any suggestions? Thanks!!!
(i'm using the tiny-za server btw)

Comment: put your code "click" in the document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current link the user clicked on in your initial argument `e`, via the property `e.currentTarget`:

```
$findUl.on('click', function(e){
  // this gives you the DOM node that was clicked:
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
}
```

A little shortcut to get the title using jQuery:

```
$findUl.on('click', function(e){
  var title = $(e.currentTarget).text();
}
```

Another note, you should really only be loading the data from the server in that `ajax` call once, not every time something is clicked (which is sloooow).

I'd recommend loading the data into an object when the page loads, then using the obejct properties to append to the DOM. You'll be able to access that same object in future click handlers